# Server Action fetch swallowing custom error from backend service

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch

I am performing a Server Action for a form submission in a file called `action.js`.

In the `action.js` I am fetching a `POST` request to a backend service like so:

```
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://my.backend.xyz/service', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(myData)
    });

    const Errmsg = await response.json();

    console.log('here?', Errmsg);
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

The fetch call to the backend service fails and the service is returning a custom error message but for some reason it does not log out in the `console.log`.

When I make the fetch call in the browser I see the custom error message. Does the backend fetch call swallow the custom error? Is there a way to see the errors coming from the backend service?